# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.a accessible

Tags: java, apache-flink, pojo

I can not make access to java pojo in visual studio codes maven.

```
OS : Windows 11
JDK : open-jdk 17.0.2
maven : apache-maven 3.9.6
apache flink : 1.18.1 (installed on WSL 2 ubuntu)
visual studio code : x64 1.87.2
```

Belows are the simple flink mongodb sink codes.

**== Car.java (POJO class)**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
 
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Car{
 
    private String brand;
    private int price;
}
```

**== Flink MongoDB Sink codes**

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setParallelism(1);

List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
cars.add(new Car("BMW", 500));
cars.add(new Car("Kia", 300));
cars.add(new Car("Ford", 600));

DataStream<Car> stream = env.fromCollection(cars);

MongoSink<Car> sink = MongoSink.<Car>builder()
            .setUri("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
            .setDatabase("class_db")
            .setCollection("class_coll")
            .setBatchSize(1000)
            .setBatchIntervalMs(1000)
            .setMaxRetries(3)
            .setDeliveryGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
            .setSerializationSchema(
                    (input, context) 
                        -> {
                            Document doc = new Document(input.getBrand(), input.getPrice());
                            System.out.println(doc);
                            return new InsertOneModel<>(BsonDocument.parse(doc.toJson()));
                        })
            .build();

stream.sinkTo(sink);

env.execute("MongoDB POJO Test");
env.close();
```

The above codes contain no bugs except this exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Serializing the source elements failed: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.a accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @2a32de6c
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.FromElementsFunction.setOutputType(FromElementsFunction.java:162)  
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.trySetOutputType(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:84)  
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.setOutputType(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:60)     
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.setOutputType(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:146)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SimpleOperatorFactory.setOutputType(SimpleOperatorFactory.java:118)       
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.addOperator(StreamGraph.java:434)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.addOperator(StreamGraph.java:402)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.addLegacySource(StreamGraph.java:356)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.translators.LegacySourceTransformationTranslator.translateInternal(LegacySourceTransformationTranslator.java:66)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.translators.LegacySourceTransformationTranslator.translateForStreamingInternal(LegacySourceTransformationTranslator.java:53)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.translators.LegacySourceTransformationTranslator.translateForStreamingInternal(LegacySourceTransformationTranslator.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.SimpleTransformationTranslator.translateForStreaming(SimpleTransformationTranslator.java:62)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.translate(StreamGraphGenerator.java:860)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.transform(StreamGraphGenerator.java:590)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.getParentInputIds(StreamGraphGenerator.java:881)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.translate(StreamGraphGenerator.java:839)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.transform(StreamGraphGenerator.java:590)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.generate(StreamGraphGenerator.java:328)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2289)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2280)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2266)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2093)
        at com.aaa.test.FlinkMongoClassTest.main(FlinkMongoClassTest.java:49)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Serializing the source elements failed: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.a accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @2a32de6c
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.FromElementsFunction.serializeElements(FromElementsFunction.java:139)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.FromElementsFunction.setOutputType(FromElementsFunction.java:160)  
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.a accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @2a32de6c
        at com.twitter.chill.java.ArraysAsListSerializer.<init>(ArraysAsListSerializer.java:69)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.FlinkChillPackageRegistrar.registerSerializers(FlinkChillPackageRegistrar.java:67)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.getKryoInstance(KryoSerializer.java:513)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.checkKryoInitialized(KryoSerializer.java:522)      
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.serialize(KryoSerializer.java:348)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.FromElementsFunction.serializeElements(FromElementsFunction.java:136)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object[] java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.a accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @2a32de6c
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
```

So I change the class of input stream to Tuple2 from Car class like below

```
List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> cars = new ArrayList<>();
cars.add(new Tuple2<>("BMW", 500));
cars.add(new Tuple2<>("Kia", 300));
cars.add(new Tuple2<>("Ford", 600));

DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> stream = env.fromCollection(cars);
```

Then everything goes right without any errors. It seems that the main java codes can not make access to Car POJO class. Any reply will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The error message references `private final java.lang.Object[]` in your Car class, which I don't see from the code you posted above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the codes of Car class I post above are all codes I type in. There is no 'final' keyword in Car class codes. So I can not understand this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on Kryo to serialize your `Car` object. From the error message, I think maybe your `Car` class has a final field (array of objects), which Kryo can't set when deserializing an object.

Comment: I solved it myself. I insert @NoArgsConstructor annotation into Car class and it works without errors. The default constructor with no arguments is the mandatory configuration in POJO serialization. I found the clue in this link, https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/types_serialization/ . Thanks any way. ;)